# Use function globally or locally?

Tags: python

In Python I have several functions that use the location of the user's directory as a way of determining where to put files.

I currently use a "global" variable for all the functions to use.

```
home = os.path.expanduser('~')
```

I'm wondering if this is good coding practice.

The upside of this is that the program only needs to execute this code only once.
I could also have each function call `os.path.expanduser` each time it is called.

Which is the more pythonic one? Or is there a pythonicer way?

Comment: constant global variables are fine. Although, in this case, I would use `import os; HOME =  os.environ['HOME']`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga why? What's wrong with `expanduser`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with globals. It's a consequence of how you designed your program. You wrote a few functions and put them in a module, and globals are a way to share data between individual functions in a module.

For example, had you decided to go with an object oriented design, then one could argue that globals should be avoided and shared data should be encapsulated. But you didn't do that, so globals are fine.

Comment: I've also thought that maybe putting the functions in a `class` would be a good way forward.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to use global constants. At the end all the first-level function and classes defined in the same module are also "global" in this sense.

Using gobal variables becomes messy when different components of the system start re-assigning their values or mutate their content. In this case it's an obvious antipattern and can lead to a debugging hell.